# How do I get to cousin elements with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with many rows of data, and I want to show or hide some of the details on each row based on a checkbox in the first element.  For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="aspnetweirdness"><input type=checkbox></span></td>
    <td>Text Text Text</td>
    <td><select /></td>
    <td><input type=text></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking to traverse from the checkbox to the cousin elements (the text, the select, and the text input) with jquery and toggle the visibility on those elements based on whether the checkbox is checked.  One small snag is that the checkbox is wrapped in a span, since this is being output by asp.net.  That also makes the elements harder to get at by id.

How would I go about doing this?  I've tried $(this).parentsUntil('tr').siblings(), but it doesn't seem like i get the right elements.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
 $(".crewMemberTable input:checkbox").toggle(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('select, input:not(:checkbox)').fadeIn();
            $(this).closest('tr').find('label').css('font-weight', 'bold');
        }, function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('select, input:not(:checkbox)').fadeOut();
            $(this).closest('tr').find('label').css('font-weight', 'normal');
        });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well have you tried:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:first-child)')
```

where "this" would be your checkbox element if the code were in a "click" handler or something.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled across it and realized I recently wrote a generic function for this.

Using the function below you could simply write `$(this).cousins()` to get a collection containing the text, select, and text-input elements (where `this` is of course your checkbox.)

```
/* See http://addictedtonew.com/archives/414/creating-a-jquery-plugin-from-scratch/
 * Used like any other jQuery function:
 *        $( selector ).cousins()
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.cousins = function() {
        var cousins;
        this.each(function() {
            var auntsAndUncles = $(this).parent().siblings();
            auntsAndUncles.each(function() {
                if(cousins == null) {
                    cousins = auntsAndUncles.children();
                }
                else cousins.add( auntsAndUncles.children() );
            });
        });
        return cousins;
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ancestors` be better named `auntsAndUncles`, since they won't technically be ancestors of the current node?

Comment: I actually thought about naming that variable `auntsAndUncles`, but decided `ancestors` was simpler. I would also argue aunts and uncles technically *are* ancestors, but that's a question for english.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: I don't agree - and neither do dictionaries or wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancestor http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ancestor but I guess you could ask over at english for another opinion.

However, I still like your answer, so I gave you the upvote anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('select,input').hide();
});
```

Comment: Actually he probably doesn't always want to hide the other elements; he'd probably want to show them when the checkbox is checked, and hide them otherwise, or else maybe vice-versa.

Comment: I realize that he doesn't want to always hide them. It was an example of how to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to stackoverflow and I'm not sure if I can or not, but I edited the answer of @robjb and posting here. Full credit goes to him only.

In case if anyone wants to select only particular cousins and not all cousins (i.e. wants to have selector), then we can use this modified version of @robjb 's answer. If *selector* is not passed as an argument then it will give all cousins.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.cousins = function(selector) {
    var cousins;
    this.each(function() {
        var auntsAndUncles = $(this).parent().siblings();
        auntsAndUncles.each(function() {
            if(cousins == null) {
                if(selector)
                    cousins = auntsAndUncles.children(selector);
                else
                    cousins = auntsAndUncles.children();
            }
            else {
                if(selector)
                    cousins.add( auntsAndUncles.children(selector) );
                else
                    cousins.add( auntsAndUncles.children() );
            }
        });
    });
    return cousins;
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Example use of the above function would be as

```
$(clickedObj).cousins('.singleWheel');
```

The other option would be to use .filter() and use @robjb's  answer.