# jQuery find text between tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disclaimer: Yes, I am aware of the mess this HTML is.  It's from a legacy application. Unfortunately, changing HTML is not an option, since it is a large page with many dependencies.

That said, I have the below code:

```
<tr>
    <th align="left" style="background:#CCCCCC;" nowrap="">
        <a class="ContentLink addLink" id="content">
            <img border="0" src="/tools/images/buttons/restore.gif" alt="edit (popup)">Add
        </a>
    </th>
    <th colspan="3" nowrap="" width="100%">
        <font id="maroon">Associated Computer(s)</font>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Using jQuery, I would like to get the string between the `font` tags "Associated Computer(s)".

I've tried using jQuery's `find` and `next` APIs, but it's not working as I expect.

I've tried `var myHeader_next = $(this).find("font");` and it returns an object. When I use `var myHeader_trim = $.trim(myHeader_next);`, I get `[object Object]`.

I've tried `var myHeader_next = $(this).find("font").text();` and `var myHeader_trim = $.trim(myHeader_next);` and for both, I get blank responses.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addLink").click(function(){
        var SR_ID = $("#SR_ID").val();
        var myHeader_next = $(this).find("font").text();
        var myHeader_trim = $.trim(myHeader_next);
        console.log(myHeader_next);
        console.log(myHeader_trim);
    });     
});
```

I have a feeling I'm not understanding `find` and `next` correctly, but don't know why.

Comment: .find only looks at children of the selected element. you want to look for a cousin, so you'll have to get the parent of the cousin element and then use find.

Comment: Will that element always have a known id?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will always have a known id.  The tags will be `<font id="maroon>Some Random Text</font>` repeated 5 times.

Comment: Going with @KevinB's suggestion, I see the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381757/how-do-i-get-to-cousin-elements-with-jquery.  I haven't encountered the term cousin before, so I didn't know it was an option. This lines up with talemyn's suggestion.

Comment: Although it's not valid, since you've already made mention of the fact that the quality of the HTML isn't great, I have to ask if there will ever be more than one row with `<font id="maroon">`?  If so, then using `$('#maroon')` will only ever return the first instance of those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to find it would be:

```
var myHeader_next = $(this).closest("tr").find("font");
```

That will travel up the DOM change until it finds the first ancestor `<tr>` and then `.find("font")` finds all of the `<font>` tags in the `<tr>` tags descendants.

At that point, you should have the correct `<font>` element that you are looking for and `.text()` will work.

Comment: This thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381757/how-do-i-get-to-cousin-elements-with-jquery), in conjunction to @KevinB's comment helped point me in this direction as well.

Comment: Yeah, the "closest/find" combination is pretty common when dealing with data in a table format, since you usually need to hop from the content of one table cell to another, and since there are always multiple levels of elements, due to the nature of table structures (i.e., so `.parent()` and `sibling()` will rarely work).

Answer (score 2):

You can use .html().

```
$('#maroon').html()
```

returns

```
Associated Computer(s)
```

Comment: The only concern that I would have with this approach is that, since "maroon" an `id` value, then it must be unique, so, if any other rows need to use this functionality, that selector would not work for them.

Comment: Ahhh . . . just saw his comment.

Comment: But what if that tag contains another tag. using `.html()` will also return that tag and its value. What if my condition is not to select the inner tag or its value but only its value?
Example: `<button>Hello <a>Link<a> <button>`
In this case if I use `button.html()` then it will return `Hello <a>Link<a> ` which is not good because I only need `Hello`.

Comment: Ok I got the answer from the question lol. We can do it by using `.text()`.