# How can I access a cousin element, of an element with an identifier in Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I am trying to click a check box in a list of Table rows
the only way I can think to access this level is by the span tag with its corresponding name.

```
cy.get('tr > td > span').contains('newCypressTestCore').siblings('td > input').click();
```

Although this would only return the siblings of the span tag when I actually need to access the cousin of the `span` tag.

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" />
   </td>
   <td>
     <span> newCypressTestCore </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress uses jquery, so this answer is useful [How do I get to cousin elements with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381757/how-do-i-get-to-cousin-elements-with-jquery).

The `closest()` selector scans up the tree, use it to get the row, then within that the input.

**spec**

```js
describe('cousins', () => {
  it('scans up the table', () => {

    cy.visit('app/table.example.html')

    cy.get('tr > td > span').contains('newCypressTestCore')
      .closest('tr')
      .find('input')
      .should('have.class', 'target')

  })
})
```

**app/table.example.html** (sandboxed - [Cypress can optionally act as your web server](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html#Web-Server))

```js
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="not.the.input.you.are.looking.for" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span> something </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="target" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span> newCypressTestCore </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"  class="not.the.input.you.are.looking.for" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span> another thing </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use with `.parents()` to identify the parent class of the table and then use `find()` to narrow down till the `input` checkbox field is identified. See the below piece of code and see if that work;

```
cy.get('input[type="checkbox]').parents('.lh-copy').find('tr').find('td').find('input').click();
```

or may be try with immediate parent class of `td`

```
cy.get('input[type="checkbox]').parents('.hover-bg-near-white').find('td').find('input').click();
```